# Why is it after I unhollow, use Humanity and kill things, I gain Humanity?

Tags: steam, dark-souls

Why is it after I use Humanity, unhollow, and kill things, I gain Humanity back in the upper left hand corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first several enemies killed in an area will give you Humanity. Not one for one, but killing a certain number will get you 1 Humanity. This will only happen once per area. It doesn't matter if you are hollowed or not.

Comment: While I'm not sure you're wrong, I know you can get more humanity by continuously killing enemies -- you're not limited to only getting 1 humanity (at least up until the area's boss is defeated). Rats are particularly good for this.

Comment: Some enemies have a chance to drop humanity regardless if you're human or hollow, rats have especially high humanity drop rate.

Comment: @Chippies I believe you are referring to the Humanity *item* (or "Hard Humanity"), whereas the OP is referring to the Humanity counter on the HUD ("Soft Humanity").

Comment: @RavenDreamer I believe you might be as well. If that's the case. you can still farm the Humanity item from enemies (such as rats) long after the boss' demise.

Comment: I don't understand why people don't bother checking wikis for this sort of thing. Soft humanity drops from certain enemies in areas where you haven't defeated the boss yet. See [here](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/humanity-farming#toc6). In addition, there is a hidden humanity meter that you need to fill in order to gain said soft humanity. Hard humanity, which is the item form, drops consistently from other enemies still.

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238546/what-is-the-percentage-of-getting-liquid-humanity-and-what-affects-it)

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to gain Humanity, one is using the item, another is recovering your bloodstain when you had Humanity in the counter.

The third way (the one you are describing) is to kill humanoids. After a number of kills you will gain a Humanity. Each area with humanoid enemies can grant 10 Humanity this way, but only if the area boss is not killed.

As Yuuki has mentioned, some enemies drop Humanity as an item. Rats are quite good for this, though there are better enemies later in the game.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said, not only will certain enemies drop humanity as an item, *the higher your humanity the better drop chance you have.*  The cap is 10. Equip some item find gear and grind away. You will more than make back those 10.

[Here is a youtube guide explaining the process.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDCEhXNtSPw) Good luck!